# PHP recursive function issue.

Tags: php, css, recursion

I am having a php recursive function to display my categories with sub, sub-sub category.

Its look like below:

```
function displayList(&$cats, $parent, $current=0, $level=0) {
  if ($parent==0) {
    foreach ($cats[$parent] as $id=>$nm) {
        displayList($cats, $id, $current);
    }
  }
  else {
    echo "<ul>\n";        
    foreach ($cats[$parent] as $id=>$nm) {
      $sel = $current==$id ? ' active' : '';        

      //$indent = str_repeat('&ndash; ', $level);
      echo "<li><a href='' class='$sel'>$nm</a>\n";
      if (isset($cats[$id])) {
          displayList($cats, $id, $current, $level+1);  //increment level
      }
      echo '</li>';
    }
    echo "</ul>\n";
  }  
}
```

Here I want to add a `CSS` class for each parent `<li>`, if it has a sub, sub-sub categories.

My HTML is something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="product_category.html">Party Balloons</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Party Tableware</a></li>
  <li class="parent"><a href="">Party Decorations</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </a></li>
    <li class="parent"><a href="">Conse ctetur adipisicing </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Dolore magna aliqua</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Ut labore et </a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Elit sed do eiusmod tempor</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Incididunt ut labor</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Party Banners</a></li>
</ul>
```

Can anybody tell me how can I do it? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider using JavaScript to iterate all `li` tags and count the number of `li` parents above them.

Answer (score 1):

This probably does not address your question accurately (not using PHP), but you can consider using jQuery:

```
$("li").filter(function(){
    return $(this).find("li").length > 0; // counts children with <li> recursively
}).addClass("has-sublist");
```